# Does that mean an object doesn't need to be cleared manually if it doesn't implement IDisposable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, memory

The problem I'm facing is the following error:

**System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The operation completed successfully**

Stack trace:

```
at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.RegisterClassEx(WNDCLASSEX_D wc_d)
at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper..ctor(Int32 classStyle, Int32 style, Int32 exStyle, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, String name, IntPtr parent, HwndWrapperHook[] hooks)
at MS.Win32.MessageOnlyHwndWrapper..ctor()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher..ctor()
at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.get_CurrentDispatcher()
at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject..ctor()
at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder..ctor(SafeMILHandle decoderHandle, BitmapDecoder decoder, Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, Boolean insertInDecoderCache, Boolean isOriginalWritable, Stream uriStream, UnmanagedMemoryStream unmanagedMemoryStream, SafeFileHandle safeFilehandle)
at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.JpegBitmapDecoder..ctor(SafeMILHandle decoderHandle, BitmapDecoder decoder, Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, Boolean insertInDecoderCache, Boolean originalWritable, Stream uriStream, UnmanagedMemoryStream unmanagedMemoryStream, SafeFileHandle safeFilehandle)
at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy, Boolean insertInDecoderCache)
at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.Create(Stream bitmapStream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption)
at App.Business.WPFImageService.ReadBitmapFrame(Stream stream)
at App.Business.WPFImageService.UploadFileToAmazon(String amazonPath, Boolean isBlankImage)
```

By doing some research, I've found that this issue happens when number of `Handles` exceeds 10k for the process. And this happens if I forgot to call `.Dispose()` method.

In my application, I've clearly (100% sure) disposing every single object that implements `IDisposable`.

While I am still facing this issue, now I'm not sure that every object that has to be cleared after usage, implements `IDisposable`.

I'm using the following kind of objects in my app.

`BitmapFrame`, `DrawingVisual`, `DrawingContext`, `RenderTargetBitmap`, `SolidColorBrush`, `BitmapDecoder`, `Stream`, `MemoryStream`, `FileStream`, `PngBitmapEncoder`.

`Stream`, `MemoryStream` and `FileStream` implements `IDisposable` which I'm clearly calling `Dispose()` on them. But, `DrawingContext` doesn't implement `IDisposable` however has a `.Close()` method, which is also being called.

Other objects has no `.Dispose()`, `.Close()`, `Flush()` or anything that can be related to the topic.

I'm stuck, why my handles are exceeding 10k (I've checked that from task managed, by adding Handle column). This application did not have this issue before I add some image processing functions using WPF/WIC.

Any ideas?

Comment: VS intellicense is not showing me `.Dispose()` on my `DrawingContext` which is resulting me a compile error.

Comment: but it has `.Close()` method. and `DrawingContext` declaration is wrapped with `using` statement anyways in the code.

Comment: yes, you are right at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext(v=vs.110).aspx). `DrawingContext` implements `IDisposable`. Then arises another question. Why it doesn't have `.Dispose` method if it implements `IDisposable`, and why wrapping `DrawingContext` with `using` doesn't ensure that the handles are being deleted at the end of the method?

Comment: Ok. I'll looked up #1. But why you think I'm on the wrong way of troubleshooting the leaks?

Comment: But my methods are not long running and I'm not using threads. Then is my problem is a `WPF` bug? Or I went wrong again?

Comment: My problem is still not solved, I can't find a work around for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to make sure you also try using statement to make sure you get garbage collection

```
  using (DrawingContext dc = dGroup.Open())
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: that is exactly how I do. but like this `using (var targetContext = targetVisual.RenderOpen())`

Comment: this is how the current code is, which doesn't solve the issue and logically tells me that the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: you have to make sure you render DrawingContext as soon as you intiate it

Comment: then you need to make sure you are collecting garbage everywhere

Comment: I'm rendering `DrawingContext` on next line, right after the initiation of the `DrawingVisual`, like you said. And also, I know that freeing up the `Handles` is not job of the `GC`, and they are only deleted once you call `.Dispose()`. Which means, I'm doing what you think I should be doing.

Comment: which part you belive causing issue maybe it not even garbage collection

Comment: `using` will be integrated to `try/finally` code block on compile. and in `finally` block there is `.Dispose()` and `.Close()`. all the object that has dispose and close are being disposed and closed. but my handles are still more than 10k. I can't call `GC.Collect()` because I think it doesn't solve the problem, as it is not job of the `GC` to free up the handles.

Comment: My problem is still not solved, I can't find a work around for this issue.