# Windows service: using of BitmapEncoder or BitmapDecoder ends with «The operation completed successfully»

Tags: c#, wpf, image, service

I am facing a problem that I am not able to solve or google solution anywhere.

I am running service that load or saves images and uses `BitmapEncoder` or `BitmapDecoder` classes. After some time (depending how often I save/load images) service refuse to save/load images. First I see warning in event log with

> heap allocation failed

I googled what does it mean and it has to do with limited number of GDI objects that Windows service has. Its possible to modify registry to increase number of these object but its not very nice solution I think and also it does not work for me.

My code throws following exception with stack trace when saving

```
Error while storing image : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The operation completed successfully
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper..ctor(Int32 classStyle, Int32 style, Int32 exStyle, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, String name, IntPtr parent, HwndWrapperHook[] hooks)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapEncoder..ctor(Boolean isBuiltIn)
   at Imaging.TiffReadWrite.Save(String filename, Image img)
```

and when loading

```
Error while loading image : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The operation completed successfully
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper..ctor(Int32 classStyle, Int32 style, Int32 exStyle, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, String name, IntPtr parent, HwndWrapperHook[] hooks)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject..ctor()
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder..ctor(Stream bitmapStream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, Guid expectedClsId)
   at Imaging.TiffReadWrite.Load(String filename)
```

My code for saving images looks like:

```
public static void Save(string filename, BitmapSource img)
{
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
    {
        TiffBitmapEncoder encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Compression = TiffCompressOption.None;

        BitmapFrame frm = BitmapFrame.Create(img);

        encoder.Frames.Add(frm);
        encoder.Save(stream);
    }
}
```

and for loading images looks like:

```
public static BitmapSource Load(string filename)
{
    BitmapSource resultImage = null;

    using (Stream imSource = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
    {
        var decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(imSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
        resultImage = decoder.Frames[0];
    }
    return resultImage;
}
```

So, service refuses to save/load images. I can try/catch this exception so the service can continue running, but no images could be saved/load. Sometimes after first occurrence of this exception few images could be saved/loaded and after a while no saving/loading is performed.

My only workaround for this problem is not running this code in service but in application. Then it runs just fine, but that is not a solution I am looking for. If anyone has any better suggestion please let me know.

There are some similar posts (stack trace of exception is more or less the same) that is not actually solved:

- [Image Resizing : The operation completed successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588307/image-resizing-the-operation-completed-successfully)
- [Does that mean an object doesn't need to be cleared manually if it doesn't implement IDisposable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22153583/does-that-mean-an-object-doesnt-need-to-be-cleared-manually-if-it-doesnt-imple)
- [Windows.Media.Imaging Thumbnail generation causing exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467564/windows-media-imaging-thumbnail-generation-causing-exceptions)

Comment: Well, that's a pretty useless exception message.  Services run in session 0, it has an intentionally small desktop heap.  That makes it more likely that CreateWindowEx() will fail.  Could be another service taking its unfair share btw.  Or yours, the "User Objects" counter in Task Manager is your first diagnostic.  You also run a risk of not having the GC collect often enough, you may need to help by calling GC.Collect() yourself every N bitmaps.  The fact that there is no meaningful error code does point at an environmental problem however.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know its vague and that's why I am not able to solve it. I check Task manager and I used dheapmon to track GDI object where I only found out that WinLogon has high use rate but that's all. It could be another service but it was observed on different PCs on different services that uses code I posted. So not very likely. I think I already have more than enough GC.Collect() calls. So this wont help either.

Comment: @TomKos, consider using the `BitmapCacheOption.None` value as the constructor argument of the `TiffBitmapDecoder` class and as the argument of the `BitmapFrame.Create()` method call.

Comment: WPF doesn't use GDI. But that could be related to thread model. Is your code running in an STA thread? Can you share more of your code so we can reproduce (PS: WPF is not supported in server code)?

Comment: @SergeyBrunov, I will try that.

Comment: @SimonMourier, My code has problem with running as Windows service but as WPF application it runs just fine. Its not running in STA thread. Its asynchronous operation. I think I shared the critical part of my code. This is the part where exception is thrown. You should be able to reproduce it although it might be tricky depending how much you would stress it.

Comment: If you can't give a small complete reproducing code, I can't help you

Comment: I understand that its not easy to reproduce as i stated because it occurs after a while(hours, days). But otherwise there is all what you need. Just create a loop where you will save/load images(preferably big one >100MB) and do it in Windows service.

Answer (score 3):

> The operation completed successfully

This mystifying message narrows down the exact code in the HwndWrapper constructor that fails.  WPF has a bug in the [GetStockObject](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Shared/MS/Win32/UnsafeNativeMethodsCLR.cs,d5ccf0edee77e6e6) pinvoke declaration.  Its `SetLastError = true` property is wrong, GetStockObject() does not in fact produces an error code.  You see the description of error code 0, "nothing went wrong".

GetStockObject() is a winapi function that never fails if it gets the correct argument.  Stock objects are pre-allocated and never released.  You have very strong evidence that the process state is thoroughly corrupted.  Seeing a "heap allocation failed" message in the event log is certainly part of that misery.

If you have no idea what could cause this corruption, machine is known-good with reliable RAM, you are not running any dangerous native code and the machine is not running any other services that could corrupt the desktop heap, then the only alternative you have is to create a minidump of the crashed process.  Call Microsoft Support, they can follow the trace from the GetStockObject() failure.  Do beware that you'll have to get through the first support layers, the ones that will tell you to swap the machine out :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I appreciate your explanation. I might try to call Microsoft Support but I dont have much hope in that. Meanwhile I dont see how could I solve this.